# vBasic time in textbox decrementing

Tags: timer, controls

Working in visual studio 2012 .

I have readed the value to textbox from mysql database in time format ex (00:15:10) .

I set the timer on my form and when timer tick i want to decrement the time to 00:15:09 
next timer tick 00:15:08
next timer tick 00:15:07  .....

Till time come's to 0. Then it will popup msgbox to show that "Time run out "

I used this code, but to be honest i didn't expect it will work.

```
   Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    TextBox1.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text) - 1
    If Val(TextBox1.Text) <= 0 Then
        MsgBox(" Time run out ")
    End If
End Sub
```

Im really sorry but my english is bad .  Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

This code is really close to solution

```
Public Class frmSinglePlayer

Private TargetDT As DateTime
Private CountDownFrom As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3)

Private Sub frmSinglePlayer_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    tmrCountdown.Interval = 500
    TargetDT = DateTime.Now.Add(CountDownFrom)
    tmrCountdown.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub tmrCountdown_Tick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmrCountdown.Tick
    Dim ts As TimeSpan = TargetDT.Subtract(DateTime.Now)
    If ts.TotalMilliseconds > 0 Then
        lblTime.Text = ts.ToString("mm\:ss")
    Else
        lblTime.Text = "00:00"
        tmrCountdown.Stop()
        MessageBox.Show("Done")
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class